# How to configure ESLint for using e.g. event.target and element.parentNode?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

**Edit:** I didn't realize the error messages are not even coming from ESLint but from something called [js] in **Visual Studio Code**. I'd delete the question but it might help others also mistaking the [js] output for ESLint. Still curious to learn what sort of process this `[js]` thing is.

I have been presented with the task to define a project-wide .eslintrc.js file to make sure the team's code meets common standards.

Running ESLint using preset `eslint:recommended` gives me the following error message

```
The property "parentNode" does not exist for the type "EventTarget".
```

This is the piece of code in question:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  const currentTag = event.target.parentNode.tagName;
  /* ... */
})
```

I understand that there can be `event.target`s that are **not** `HTMLElement`s, **but how am I supposed to code - or configure ESLint - so this line no longer produces ESLint errors? We are planning on making our build fail as long as ESLint reports any errors, so this *must* be addressed.**

A second line of code that causes a similar error:

```
document.activeElement.click();
```

results in ESLint erroring

```
The property "click" does not exist for the type "Element".
```

3rd example:

```
const rows = this.childNodes[1].querySelectorAll('tr');
```

throws

```
The property "querySelectorAll" does not exist for the type "Node & ChildNode".
```

Note: Please do not suggest the use of flow or Typescript, the code will remain pure ES6 (which I understand **ES**Lint is for).

Comment: Just disable a that buggy rule?

Comment: Nitpick: flow types can be annotated in comments, so it *is* pure JavaScript. But yeah, that seems like a weird linter error.

Comment: @Bergi What would that "buggy" rule be? I'm using the `eslint:recommended` preset (like probably hundreds of thousands of others).

Comment: @connexo The complete error message should always mention which rule it comes from

Comment: Seems like ESLint is trying to provide type safety, which seems a little too ambitious for a linter.

Comment: This looks like TypeScript not eslint, maybe this is your IDE implicitly trying to type hint your code?

Comment: @connexo Also I kinda doubt that the message is actually coming from eslint at all

Comment: Please close this as I didn't realize the error messages are not even coming from ESLint but from something called `[js]` in Visual Studio Code. I'd delete it but it might help others also mistaking the [js] output for ESLint.

Comment: Please check if this was it ? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_linters

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan Please add that, along with one or two lines of text, as an answer that I can accept. The code in question indeed has `// @ts-check` as first line.

Comment: @connexo added the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP the code contains // @ts-check as first line

Thus it's pretty clear that this has nothing to do with separate eslint, but is caused by internal [VSCode linter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_linters)

> The easiest way to enable type checking in a JavaScript file is by adding // @ts-check to the top of a file.